# How to retrieve last item in StringCollection array

Tags: vb.net, stringcollection

I'm trying to get the last item in string collection array with this:

```
scWords(0).Item(0) & "-" & scWords(0).Item(scWords(0).Count))
```

It keeps saying out of range

Comment: arrays and collections are zero based, so `Count-1` is the index of the last item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array/collection in .NET has zero-based indexing. This means that the first entry is referred to as 0 rather than 1.

Consider this list:

```
0 Apple
1 Orange
2 Kiwi
3 Watermelon
```

The list clearly has 4 items in it, but since it's 0-based indexing, the last item (Watermelon) is `3`, not `4`. This is why when you use `.Count` (which returns *how many items the list has*), it says out of range.

As you can see from the example, using `.Count -1` will return the last item.

Answer (score 0):

That's another solution. If you do not want to use "count"

```
aArray(Array.LastIndexOf(aArray, Not Nothing) + 1)
```